# Configuring a bridge leads to losing connection

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, vlan, bonding

I have a Linux server with three NIC that are connected to a switch (one NIC is the management, two NIC form a LACP bonding). In addition I need to use a VLAN (167), because the switch is configured with it.

Huawei switch (Management):

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/14
description #### MGMT ####
port link-type access
port default vlan 166
```

Huawei switch (bonding/LACP):

```
interface Eth-Trunk10
description #### Server ####
port link-type trunk
port trunk allow-pass vlan 167
stp disable
mode lacp
load-balance src-dst-mac
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address  200.200.200.2
netmask  255.255.255.248
post-up ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via 200.200.200.1 dev enp3s0

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
bond-miimon 100
bond-mode 802.3ad
bond-lacp-rate 1

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet static
address 100.100.100.2
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 100.100.100.1
vlan-raw-device bond1
```

So, this configuration works on both ends. I can reach the management and I can send out and receive traffic on the bonding's end.

As the server is the host for several VMs I need to configure a bridge and there start my problems. As soon as I configure a bridge on the bonding interface (or the management, whatever sense that would make), the server/connection is getting unstable, immediately. It loses the link several times per hour, sometimes blocking me five, sometimes 30 minutes.

But the address stays pingable all the time, which I do not understand quite right. It looks like a software-defined connection refusal, but I have no firewall active.

This is the configuration with the bridge:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address  200.200.200.2
netmask  255.255.255.248
post-up ip route add 1.1.1.1/32 via 200.200.200.1 dev enp3s0

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
bond-miimon 100
bond-mode 802.3ad
bond-lacp-rate 1

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
bond-master bond1

auto bond1.167
iface bond1.167 inet manual
vlan-raw-device bond1

auto vmbr1v167
iface vmbr1v167 inet static
address 100.100.100.2
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway 100.100.100.1
bridge-ports bond1.167
bridge-stp off
bridge-fd 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did this now and it seems to work this far.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
    address 100.100.100.18
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    post-up ip route add 40.40.40.40/32 via 100.100.100.17 dev enp3s0

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
    bond-slaves eno1 enp4s0
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-mode 802.3ad
    bond-lacp-rate 1

iface enp4s0 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

iface eno1 inet manual
    bond-master bond1

iface bond1.167 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
    bridge_ports bond1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1v167
iface vmbr1v167 inet static
   address 200.200.200.114
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   gateway 200.200.200.113
   bridge_ports bond1.167
   bridge_stp off
   bridge_fd 0
```